# Who is Shivananda Swami?

Tags: shiva, durga, puja, saint

There are popular aartis, that are sung in North, which have initials of Swami Shivananda in their end. For example

[image]

[image]

So, my question is, who is "Swami Shivananda", composer of such Aartis?

Comment: A lot of info on Sri Sivananda Saraswati (Swami Sivananda) is available on google.

Comment: I don't know both are same or not. but here's a [Swami Sivananda](http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/)

Comment: There was also a Swami Shivananda, one of the direct disciples of Sri Ramakrishna. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivananda. I am not sure if He is the one you specifically refer to, but just another information sir. All the best

Comment: *Kahat Shivananda swami, kahat Harihar swami, mana vanchhita phal paave* ... Follow up: Who is *Harihar* swami?

Answer (score 3):

Good question!!!!
Many among the devotees who sing such Aarti don't know who is Shivanand Swami !!!!
His actual name is "Shivanand Vamdev Pandya" who later became Swami Shivanand. His life span was during 14-15 th century.
He was from Gujarat and he has written many artis in Gujarati language. Both Arti mentioned above in your question are Hindi translation of Gujarati Artis.
For more details refer [this](http://timesofindia.com/city/surat/Ma-Amba-aarti-written-by-Surti-poet/articleshow/16845786.cms) article and the book mentioned in the same article.

Comment: Hi! We are very glad that you have answered the question. Please elaborate your answer by adding more details of Swami Shivanand from the link.