# What does the word Shambhu mean?

Tags: shiva, upanishads, name

Shambhu is modified word from Swayam bhu which means "Self Born" and is another name of Brahman or Purush from Upanishads. No other Deity is called Shambhu or has a Nirakaar form like Shiva Lingam. Does it mean, what I am thinking

From Isha Upanishad

> That soul is the ultimate radiant, devoid of body, unmanifest, idle,
>   pure, good-natured-natureless, all-knowing, omniscient, excellent and
>   **self-born(Swayam bhu)**. He has been creating and distributing all the meanings since time immemorial
>
> वह आत्मा परम तेजोमय, शरीरों से रहित, अक्षत, स्नायु से रहित, शुद्ध,
>   शुभाशुभकर्म-सम्पर्कशून्य, सर्वद्रष्टा, सर्वज्ञ, सर्वोत्कृष्ट और
>   **स्वयंभू** है । वही अनादि काल से सब अर्थों की रचना और विभाग करता आया है

Comment: Are you asking the meaning of the word Shambhu or answering the question meaning of Shambhu in the body? Also, use English Translations when you are wrioting non English language. This is an English Language site.

Comment: I am your fellow user. I am asking clarification on what your question is. It is unclear at the moment. If you clarify, it would be easy to answer. Mods are probably busy now. But any member in the community can ask clarifications.

Comment: dont worry, i will improve it soon, old member of here

Comment: Even Adi Shankaracharya coined the term Shivoham(I = Shiva) in parallel to "Aham Brahmasmi"(I = Brahman) from Brihadaranyaka Upanishad highest quote of self realization(Anubhava Vakya) from Upanishads. Nothing such exists in other texts

Comment: By, `Does it mean, what I am thinking` I think you mean `Does shambhu come from "Swayam"+"bhu" and therefore also have the meaning of "self-born?"`. If this is the case, you should reword your question. As it stands it can easily be interpreted to mean `shambhu comes from "Swayam"+"bhu." Does this imply what I think it does?` without you explaining the implication you are thinking. If you mean the second scenario, you should also reword it to prevent misinterpretations. However, if you do mean the second case, then you'll need to re-rewrite it to explain what implication you have in mind.

Comment: I have just filed a complaint about rude Mods here about their deleting my comments

Answer (score 6):

I don't find Shambhu (शंभु) taken as a short-form of Svayambhu (स्वयंभु). The Sanskrit word Shambhu is made up of **Sham (शम्) + Bhu (भु)**.

[Wilson Sanskrit-English Dictionary](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/mwquery/index.html) :

> śambhu
>    śambhu [Cologne record ID=37740] [Printed book page 831]
>   śambhu m. (-mbhuḥ)
>   1 ŚIVA.
>   2 BRAHMĀ.
>   3 A Jina or Jaina sanctified teacher.
>   4 A Siddha, a demi-divine being.
>   5 A sage, a venerable man.
>   9 A kind of Asclepias.
>   **E. śam auspicious particle, bhū to be, ḍu aff.**

Refer [the scanned book](http://www.sanskrit-lexicon.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/monier/serveimg.pl?file=/scans/MWScan/MWScanjpg/mw1054-zamavyasanin.jpg):

> [image]

And

> भु
>   भु [p= 759,1] [L=151209]   mfn. (ifc.) =  2 भू, becoming being existing , produced (cf. अग्नि- , प्र-भु &c )

So, **Sham (शम्) [means](http://sanskritdictionary.com/%C5%9Bam/229679/1)** auspicious , happiness, welfare
**Bhu (भु) means** to be or source i.e becoming being existence.
Hence, **Sham (शम्) + Bhu (भु) = Shambhu (शंभु) means** source of auspicious or causing happiness.

You may take a look at [Wiktionary](https://sa.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%AD%E0%A5%81):

> शंभु [śambhu], a. [शं-भू-डु] Causing happiness, granting prosperity.

Even [BabyNamesPedia](https://www.babynamespedia.com/meaning/Shambhu) is providing useful information!

Comment: Bhu means earth or womb and not source. Shubh is auspicious and not Sham

Comment: Sham is derivative from Aham(which means I) or self. Give me reference from Sanskrit texts and not some American translation of a Malechha(Foreigner)

Comment: @Ravi I agree that Bhu means earth, however it may also have other meanings. I have provided answer according to what I find information from Sanskrit Dictionary. I may be wrong; can you provide the source for "Sham is derivative from Aham"?

Comment: the sound Ham is always refered for self, Even today "We" is called "Ham/Hum" in Hindi and Devanagri. Aham is for singular i.e A+Ham(A means not) so Aham means "not We" or "One/I". Anything ending with Ham always refers to self so be "Sham" too

Comment: @Ravi right but I don't find Aham included in Sham. Sha (श​) is itself one latter and m (म्) is suffix usually applied at the end of Sanskrit words e.g Sanskritam . So, in this case, I'm not finding Ha (ह​) at all!

Comment: M is suffix included in all sanskrit or hindi letter. Sound "Shu" means auspicious like Shubh, Shuddha but sound "Sha" is different.

Comment: @Ravi Do you remember popular Shanti Patha using that word "Sham no Mitrah Sham Varunah" [from](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21811/277) Rigveda?

Comment: its "Om Shamno Mitrah Sham Varunah" , Bhu also means Bhoot, discussion is going on here "What is meaning of Sarvabhuteshu (सर्वभूतेषु )" right now.

Comment: "Sh" is auspicious giver only if its "Shu"->"Sh"+"U"(like middle U in AUM) and not "Sha"(A means beginning) like Om or AUM(A- start/generate, U-middle/produce, M-end/destroy)

Comment: @Ravi  the root is 'bhava' and 'bhu' meaning earth is it's derivative developed later on. Try to understand meaning of 'shambhuva'

Comment: there is nothing like Shambhuva, its Shambhava Yoga, an object, that object(Tat as in Sanskrit). But Bhu is a name which is Bh+U, explained already U(as in AUM) means produce. and Sha(means Auspicious Self), Together Shambhu interprets to (producer of Auspicious Self), a way of speaking Swayambhu

Comment: @Ravi `bhu` means "Earth" in Hindi, but that is a divergence from Sanskrit where it means "be" or "become." This is most likely from `*bʰuH-` meaning "appear," or "come to be." `Cognates include Ancient Greek φύω (phúō), Avestan ‎ (bu), Latin fui and Old English beon (English be).` The connection to the Hindi "Earth" is from `bhu`'s meaning of "rise up (from)." That is, things which grow rise up from the soil, so it is their direct source of being (material and efficient cause). So, the connection to "source" isn't insignificant.

Comment: To add to Pandya's great answer, `शंभु [śambhu], a. [शं-भू-डु] Causing happiness, granting prosperity.` can be simplified to "beneficent," "benevolent," or "behoveful"/"behoving."

Comment: Do you have anything better than Babynames Pedia. Generally, they are personal info and like blogs. I think It is better to add some other site like dictionary or remove that site totally.

Answer (score 3):

Shambhu means "from whom Sham (or peace) is born (Bhu)". That is "one who is the source of peace".

See the following Mantras from Taitiriya Samhita (Sri Rudram):

> Namah **shambhave** cha mayobhave cha |
>
> Salutation to **the source of peace**, and to the source of delight.
>
> Namah **shankaraya** cha mayaskaraya cha |
>
> Salutation to **the one who creates peace (Sham)** and to the creator of
>   delight.

(Note- Shambhave means to Shambhu)

So, the word Shankara also comes from the root "Sham" meaning "peace".

(NOTE- Translations are according to the Vedic Scholar R.L.Kashyap from the Sri Aurobindo-Kapaly Shastry Institute of Vedic culture)

Comment: Shambhave and Shambhu are two different things, bhave is a bhaav or feeling, while bhu is used in sense of Noun like Bhumi, Bhur(earth), Bhuva(Space/Pitra loka) and Swarga(Heaven) . Bhu is a name which is Bh+U, explained already U(as in AUM) means produce. and Sha(means Auspicious Self), Together Shambhu interprets to (producer of Auspicious Self), a way of speaking Swayambhu

Comment: Its the same thing .... Vishnave=to Vishnu, Rahave/Ketave= To Rahu/Ketu... Because of U at the end the Vibhakti changes like that.. @Ravi So the Mantra is saying salutation to Shambhu. and Shambhu means from whom peace (Sham) is born.

Comment: Not same, a single distortion in sounds lead to wrong mantra, Wayam(as in Swayam) in Sanskrit means "We", but "Ham" as in "Sham/Aham" means "I"

Comment: Its the same .... @Ravi Shambhave means to Shambu ... namah shambave means salutation to Shambhu..

Comment: than is Amba, Ambika and Ambalika same also? Brahma, Brahmin and Brahman are same too????

Comment: Amba vibhakti will be Ambayai (because feminine), Ambika will be Ambikayai, Chandika will be Chandikyai etc.. for male deities like Ganesha it will be Ganeshaya, for Shiva Shivaya and so on... for deities which end with U it will be Ve like Vishnave, Ketave, etc... @Ravi these are the basic rules.

Comment: Ve sound in end means that it belongs to Vishnu like in "Vishnave", Shambhave means it belongs to "Shambhu", but still its Lord Vishnu not Lord Vishnave, Shambhu is not Shambhave, but Shambhave is of Shambhu, you are just making guesses, study Sanskrit and share me link where it says Ve sound is same as Noun itself

Comment: I hv studied a lil bit and what I m saying is correct it's u who need to study some of the basic things here.. @Ravi

Comment: lil bit is not enough to make claims here

Comment: @Ravi I hv given references too .. Now if u don't even know these basic things that nothing can be done.. BTW I now recognize u... Ur previous Id was Ravi J or something

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10605/who-is-shivananda-swami?noredirect=1#comment25151_10605 , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10892/what-is-the-difference-between-suktam-strotam-gayatri-and-ashtakam?noredirect=1#comment26211_10892 my questions and answers are still here, Keshav knows me

Comment: Shambhu is not Shambhave --- everyone knows that .. mantra is namaha Shambhave.. i.e Namah (salutations) to Shambhu... and Shambhu is one who creates peace.. @Ravi

Comment: Just trying to explain last time again,  sound S means good/auspicous like in "Sushil" "Sunita" , "Saundraya" etc., S+Aham(I) = Good self, Sham+Bhu = (creator of Auspicious self) i.e. self born. No peace here, Peace is "Shanti" - (Sha+Antah) means Good Ending for God sake.